# to display date in the format of ‘YYYY-MM-DD’ when the date is given in the form 1-JAN-2011?

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have to write a query to display schedule id and date in the format of ‘YYYY-MM-DD’.
can anyone help me with it

travel date is this

```
TRAVEL_DA
---------
- 09-MAY-16
- 17-MAR-16
- 26-AUG-16
- 30-APR-16
- 17-AUG-16
```

and I want to get this output

```
FORMATTEDD
--- ----------
 - 2016-05-09
 - 2016-03-17
 - 2016-08-26
 - 2016-04-30
 - 2016-08-17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(TRAVEL_DA,'%d-%b-%y'),'%Y-%m-%d') FROM TABLE;
```

For Oracle you can try [`TO_CHAR & TO_DATE`](https://community.oracle.com/message/1114903#1114903)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TRAVEL_DA,'DD-MON-YY'),'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM TABLE;
```

Sample query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('09-MAY-16','DD-MON-YY'),'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL;
```

Here sample query for same.

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('09-MAY-16','%d-%b-%y'),'%Y-%m-%d')`

Here I had added function[`DATE_FORMAT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) and [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php).

Using this two function you can resolve your issue.

Comment: Sir I am getting an error ORA-00904: "DATE_FORMAT": invalid identifier by using the above query

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `Oracle`?

Comment: I am using Oracle

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of select to do you can set the date format for your session

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD';
```

And you can remove the TO_CHAR from your requests

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TRAVEL_DA,'DD-MON-YY') FROM TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above solution this will also work in Oracle database using Symfony Doctrine with the following extensions:

https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

TO_CHAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Oracle\ToChar

TO_DATE: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Oracle\ToDate

Once loaded in doctrine.yaml the following SELECT statement will also work:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(COLUMNNAME,'DD-MON-YY'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS FIELDNAME

FROM
    Connection:Entity
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can try below query :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT (DATE_COLUMN, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM YOUR_TABLE
```